# Spyder debug error. Utf-8 codec can't decode byte. Code would run when not debugged

Tags: python, debugging, anaconda, spyder

I am using spyder v5.2 with python 3.6 (Anaconda distribution).
My script runs fine, no errors; when "*Run (f5)*" is pressed.
However, when trying to "*Debug the file (Ctrl+F5)*" the following error appears and execution stops:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Python_v1\lib\tokenize.py", line 390, in find_cookie
    line_string = line.decode('utf-8')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 22: invalid continuation byte


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "<string>", line unknown
SyntaxError: invalid or missing encoding declaration for 'c:\\users\\jruizguillen\\xxxxxxxx xx\\xxxxxxxxx xx xxxxx x xxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxx\\xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\actualizar_tabla_disp_real_mtd.py'
```

I have already eliminated any accent marks, weird characters, etc. from the file and tried copying the code in a new file.

I have also tried to change python codification using and still it is not working.

```# -*- coding:ISO-8859-1-*-````

The code:

```
import mysql.connector
import os, os.path
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

# Conexion con la base de datos
miConexion = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='111.11.111.11',
    user= 'user',
    passwd='whatever',
    db='database_data')

lista_insert = list()
deleted_files=0

# Se sacan las horas de cada mes
cur = miConexion.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM disponibildad_yte.mes")
horas_mes = cur.fetchall()

###### Archivos enviados por las zonas ######

mes_declaracion_datos = input("Seleccione el ano y mes de declaracion de datos (AAAA-MM): ") 
# Seleccionamos el mes en el que las zonas han declarado los datos

rutas_carpetas_meses = os.listdir(r"Envios zonas") 
# Carpetas de todos los meses en los que las zonas han declarado

carpeta_elegida = list(filter(lambda x: mes_declaracion_datos in x, rutas_carpetas_meses)) # Carpeta donde se encuentran los datos declarados del mes seleccionado
ruta_archivos = r"Envios zonas" + r"\\" + carpeta_elegida[0] # Ruta donde se encuentran los archivos que envian las zonas
print ("\n" + "Los datos se van a extraer de la siguiente ruta: " + ruta_archivos + "\n")
nombre_archivos = os.listdir (ruta_archivos) # Nombre de todos los archivos que se encuentran en esa carpeta
print ("Los archivos encontrados en la ruta son: \n")

for file in range (0, len (nombre_archivos)):
    if '.xlsx' in nombre_archivos[file-deleted_files]:
        print (nombre_archivos[file-deleted_files])
    else:
        nombre_archivos.pop(file-deleted_files)
        deleted_files=deleted_files + 1

print ("\n" + "Iniciando extraccion de datos e insercion en base de datos: \n")


# Version
version = datetime.strptime(mes_declaracion_datos, "%Y-%m")
# La version sera la del mes en que la zona ha declarado los datos
# Borrar la BBDD si hay algun registro previo de la misma version
delete_query="DELETE FROM disponibildad_yte.datos_indisp WHERE version = '%s'" %(version)
cur.execute(delete_query)
miConexion.commit()

for zona in range (0, len (nombre_archivos)):    
    archivo = 'Envios zonas/' + carpeta_elegida[0] + '/' + nombre_archivos[zona]
    df = pd.read_excel(archivo, sheet_name="Input", engine = 'openpyxl')
    
    for i in range (0, len(df)):
        #### Extraccion de datos en la excel e insercion en BBDD ####
        
        ## Extraccion de datos ##
        
        # Fecha de extraccion (Ano-Mes-Dia Hora:Minuto:Segundo)
        fecha_actualizacion = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        # ID de activo
        id_MOD = df["id_MOD"][i]
        # ID mes (Ano-Mes-Dia Hora:Minuto:Segundo)
        #id_mes = str(df["month"][i])
        id_mes= (str(version.year)+'-'+str(df["month"][i])+'-01 00:00:00')
        # Familia
        familia = df["Family"][i]
        # Indisponibilidad (indisponibilidad por mes)
        if (str(df["Unavailability (monthly and asset)"][i]) == "nan"): # Si no han rellenado alguna celda de la columna de indisponibilidad la ponemos a 0, sino da error
            indisponibilidad = 0
        else:
            indisponibilidad = float(df["Unavailability (monthly and asset)"][i])
        # Horas de indisponibilidad
        #for j in range (0, len(horas_mes)):
            #if str(horas_mes[j][0].month) == datetime.strptime(id_mes,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').month:
                #h = horas_mes[j][2]
        h = [tple[2] for tple in horas_mes if tple[0]== datetime.strptime(id_mes,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')][0]
                #break
        horas_indisp = float(indisponibilidad*float(df["Power"][i])*h) # Se hace el calculo de horas de indisponibilidad (indisponibilidad*potencia del parque*horas del mes)
        valores = (fecha_actualizacion, id_MOD, id_mes, familia, indisponibilidad, horas_indisp, version)
        lista_insert.append(valores)
    
    insert_query = "INSERT INTO disponibildad_yte.datos_indisp (fecha_actualizacion, id_MOD, id_mes, familia, indisponibilidad, horas_indisp, version) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    cur.executemany (insert_query, lista_insert)
    lista_insert.clear()
    miConexion.commit()
    print ("Datos de " + nombre_archivos[zona] + " extraidos e insertados en base de datos con exito \n")

print ("ACTUALIZACION DE BASE DE DATOS COMPLETADA CON EXITO")
```

Comment: "I have also tried to change python codification using and still it is not working." Exactly *how* did you try to do this? Do you know that the encoding is, in fact, UTF-8? "SyntaxError: invalid or missing encoding declaration for 'c:..." Is that the path to the file *that you are showing us*? Did you try to view the file in a **hex** editor (not text editor) to verify if there are any such bytes hiding in the data? "I have already eliminated any accent marks, weird characters, etc. from the file and tried copying the code in a new file." I can see `año` in one of the strings.

Comment: The error means the file isn't UTF8. UTF8 is an encoding just like Latin 1/ISO-8859-1, not some sort of escape sequences. If `line` is a string, it's already been converted using the encoding specified in `open`. Python 3 strings are Unicode already anyway

Comment: There's no `line_string = line.decode('utf-8')` in the code you posted. Where is that code and where does `line` come from? What you posted doesn't seem to be relevant

Comment: Thanks @KarlKnechtel! (1) To change the enconde I tried to declare # -*- coding:ISO-8859-1-*- and # -*- coding:utf-8-*-on the first line of the script. Neither of both worked. (2) Yes. that's the path of the file I am showing. (3) I tried to visualize the file in hdex.it but cant' finde anything weird. I am not very familiar with these editors thought. (4) I uploaded an old code version, eliminating the año problem still exists.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the error seems to happen in a routine called by python (tokenize: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tokenize.html); that's why the "line sequence" is not present in the code but the error is prompted when debugging my code. (thought not when running it).

Comment: The script's comments have on effect on how data files and their contents. ` # -- coding:utf-8--

Comment: That sounds like a bug in Spyder, then. `tokenize.py` is part of the tools used to interpret Python source code, which your IDE presumably does for its own checks on the code. It seems to be feeding in data that doesn't match your source file.

Comment: I have tried a simpler code (a=2 b=3 print (a) print (b); and the problem persists. Seems to be an issue of sypder debugger.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I think you are right. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Better ask on a Spyder-specific forum or issue tracker. This is no longer an on topic question here.

Comment: Thanks all! I solved the issue creating a new conda forge environment and updating spyder to 5.3 version. For reference: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/17350